# Simple_Form. Display checkboxes in a table/grid format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, checkbox, twitter-bootstrap-3, simple-form

I'm using simple_form to create a form that shows a bunch of checkboxes. These checkboxes come from an "association" (i.e. pulled from the database: their number can vary).

Simple_form outputs them in a column format (one per line). I'd like to distribute them over 3 columns (3 per line, nicely aligned).

Here is my code:

```
<%= simple_form_for @user_profile, url: wizard_path, method: :put do |f| %>
    <%= f.association :yoga_styles, as: :check_boxes, label: false%>
    </BR>
    <%= f.button :submit, "Continue" %>
<% end %>
```

I'm on Rails 4.2.3 and Bootstrap 3.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40731254/simple-form-for-how-to-create-columns-of-check-boxes-in-a-do-loop

Comment: did you figure it out